# Snap SVG rotate element around some point

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, rotation, snap.svg

I have roulette and ball in SVG. Roulette rotates around and I want to rotate ball around roulette centre. But it's rotating around other point. How to rotate it around roulette centre?

```
var bbox = ballg.getBBox(); //bounding box, get coords and centre
var scale = 2.85;
var off = 10;
ballAnimation(bbox.cx + off, bbox.cy + off, 3000, scale);

function ballAnimation(cx, cy, speed, scale){
    ballg.attr({ transform: 'r0 ' + cx + ' ' + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy }); //Reset + Scale setup
    ballg.stop(true).animate(
        { transform: "r360," + cx + ',' + cy + " s" + scale + "," + scale + "," + cx + "," + cy },
        speed,
        function(){
            ballAnimation(cx,cy, speed, scale);
        }
    );
}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DE1dds8n3ULOLQRATnLY?p=preview)

Comment: pass the ballAnimation function the wheel centre cx,cy rather than the ballg cx,cy ?